# What kind of CRC16 is this?

Tags: python, crc, crc16

I'm currently processing an AX.25 packet.
When I try to calculate the CRC/FCS myself, my result and the packet's are always different.

bitstream:
`1001101010000010100010001000101010101010101001100110000010000010100001101001111010011010011000100110110001101001000000111111000001110100011010000110100101110011001000000110100101110011001000000110000100100000011101000110010101110011011101000010000001101101011001010111001101110011011000010110011101100101001011100000101011000101`

Hex:
9A 82 88 8A AA A6 60 82 86 9E 9A 62 6C 69 03 F0 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 74 65 73 74 20 6D 65 73 73 61 67 65 2E 0A C5

The CRC is the last 16 bits: `0000101011000101`

However, I'm a bit confused about whether to reverse each byte or not since AX.25 packets are sent LSB first.

1. I've tried to calculate the CRC using an [online calculator](https://crccalc.com/). None of them fits.

input: `9A 82 88 8A AA A6 60 82 86 9E 9A 62 6C 69 03 F0 74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 74 65 73 74 20 6D 65 73 73 61 67 65 2E`

2. I've tried using python's crcmod.

```py
import crcmod

input = b"\x9A\x82\x88\x8A\xAA\xA6\x60\x82\x86\x9E\x9A\x62\x6C\x69\x03\xF0\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x61\x20\x74\x65\x73\x74\x20\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x2E"
print(input)

ploy_coeff = 0b10001000000100001
k = crcmod.Crc(poly=ploy_coeff, initCrc=0xFFFF, rev=True, xorOut=0xFFFF)
k.digest_size = 4

k.update(input)
print(hex(k.crcValue))
```

output is `0x9565`

I'd like to know how to get the correct CRC value, which bytes need to be reversed.

Comment: `"None of them fits"`? I tried the online calculator, put in the hex bytes, selected `CRC-16` and `0xC50A` pops out under `CRC-16/X-25`

Comment: I did see that the result of X-25 is 0xC50A, but I skipped it because I thought the answer is 0x0AC5, whose two bytes are reverse.

Comment: @quamrana So you are saying the CRC is using the X-25 protocol, and the resulting bytes are reverse?

Comment: The CRC you supplied matches only the X-25 settings in the online calculator and the answer I wrote is using the settings suggested to match X-25. (I am uncertain about some of the terms used)

Answer (score 0):

Python's `crcmod` defines the initial value differently than the usual convention. You need `initCrc=0`. Then you get the CRC you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a mistake in the online calculator giving the wrong init value for the crc for X-25. On the [crcmod](https://crcmod.sourceforge.net/crcmod.predefined.html) website for pre-defined algorithms it give the init value as 0:

```py
import crcmod

input = b"\x9A\x82\x88\x8A\xAA\xA6\x60\x82\x86\x9E\x9A\x62\x6C\x69\x03\xF0\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x69\x73\x20\x61\x20\x74\x65\x73\x74\x20\x6D\x65\x73\x73\x61\x67\x65\x2E"
print(input)

poly_coeff=0x11021
k = crcmod.Crc(poly=poly_coeff, initCrc=0x0, rev=True, xorOut=0xFFFF)

k.update(input)
print(hex(k.crcValue))
```

Output: `0xc50a`

Comment: No mistake in the online calculator. It has it right. crcmod uses its own unconventional convention. From the crcmod documentation: "This initial value should be the initial shift register value, reversed if it uses a reversed algorithm, and then XORed with the final XOR value." So it is the init value from the convential definition, `0xffff`, xor'ed with the final xor value, `0xffff`, to give `0`.